# анализатор речи

Tags: алгоритм

Я использую языковые автоматы для категоризации слов, но у них не всегда есть например ударение для слова, для этих целей мне кажется отлично подойдёт анализ речи, например "здрааавствуйте" явно даёт понять, что ударение на "а" или что "елка" на самом деле "ёлка" и т.д. Может кто знает в какую сторону копать? В смысле запрос или библиотека, всё что нахожу не подходит

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Вам надо библиотеку для определения где ударение в словах ставить? Или что-то другое?

Comment: да, но только с помощью звукового файла, т.к. прочие программы не подходят. Я вижу это так: звуковой файл разбивается по паузам - это слова, далее по разнице звуков - это буквы. Каждой букве присваивается время произношения, по которому я смогу определить на какую букву ударение. А вот какая программа / библиотека может это сделать и также имеет апи я и не могу найти

Comment: Так удвоение обычно не длительностью звука, а громкостью акцентируют. Да и то не всегда, бывает что ничем ударяемая гласная не выделяется.

Comment: нет, как ударение относится к громкости? слово "здарова!" как ни кричи, самой громкой будет первая "а", а продолжительной "о", которая и является ударной